# Error when adding Meta Boxes, but only when adding 3 with the same callback

Tags: metabox

I have 2 functions, one which removes the original meta boxes for 3 custom taxonomies, and one which recreates them in the desired location. The problem is that with all 3 removed, NONE of the meta boxes correctly show the 'Choose from most used' javascript (they only jump the page to the (near) top). However, if I comment out just a single 1 of the `remove_meta_box` items (it can be any of them), then the other two work as expected.

This 'works':

```
function myahts_remove_metabox()
{
    remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-ahtscollectionmakes', 'ahtscollection', 'side' );
    remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-ahtscollectionyear', 'ahtscollection', 'side' );  
    /* remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-ahtscollectionos', 'ahtscollection', 'side' ); */
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_ahtscollection' , 'myahts_remove_metabox', 1 );

function ahtscollection_metabox()
{
    add_meta_box( 'ahtscollectionmakes', __('Make', 'myahts'), 'post_tags_meta_box', 'ahtscollection', 'normal', 'high', array( 'taxonomy' => 'ahtscollectionmakes' ) );
    add_meta_box( 'ahtscollectionyear', __('Year Produced', 'myahts'), 'post_tags_meta_box', 'ahtscollection', 'normal', 'low', array( 'taxonomy' => 'ahtscollectionyear' ) );
    add_meta_box( 'ahtscollectionos', __('Operating System', 'myahts'), 'post_tags_meta_box', 'ahtscollection', 'normal', 'low', array( 'taxonomy' => 'ahtscollectionos' ) );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_ahtscollection', 'ahtscollection_metabox', 10 );
```

But this DOES NOT :

```
function myahts_remove_metabox()
{
    remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-ahtscollectionmakes', 'ahtscollection', 'side' );
    remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-ahtscollectionyear', 'ahtscollection', 'side' );  
    remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-ahtscollectionos', 'ahtscollection', 'side' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_ahtscollection' , 'myahts_remove_metabox', 1 );

function ahtscollection_metabox()
{
    add_meta_box( 'ahtscollectionmakes', __('Make', 'myahts'), 'post_tags_meta_box', 'ahtscollection', 'normal', 'high', array( 'taxonomy' => 'ahtscollectionmakes' ) );
    add_meta_box( 'ahtscollectionyear', __('Year Produced', 'myahts'), 'post_tags_meta_box', 'ahtscollection', 'normal', 'low', array( 'taxonomy' => 'ahtscollectionyear' ) );
    add_meta_box( 'ahtscollectionos', __('Operating System', 'myahts'), 'post_tags_meta_box', 'ahtscollection', 'normal', 'low', array( 'taxonomy' => 'ahtscollectionos' ) );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_ahtscollection', 'ahtscollection_metabox', 10 );
```

The `add_meta_box` shows up correctly in both instances, it just doesn't function as expected in the 2nd example.

I can't find any errors relating to this, and I can't find any documentation about why it would cause a conflict when I add a 3rd item.

Is there something I'm missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the line from `load-scripts.php`:

`var tagBox,array_unique_noempty;!function(a){array_unique_noempty=function(b){var c=[];return a.each(b,function(b,d){d=a.trim(d),d&&-1===a.inArray(d,c)&&c.push(d)}),c},tagBox={clean:function(a){var b=window.tagsBoxL10n.tagDelimiter;return","!==b&&(a=a.replace(new RegExp(b,"g"),",")),a=a.replace(/\s*,\s*/g,",").replace(/,+/g,",").replace(/[,\s]+$/,"").replace(/^[,\s]+/,""),","!==b&&(a=a.replace(/,/g,b)),a},parseTags:function(b){var c=b.id,d=c.split("-check-num-")[1],e=a(b).closest(".tagsdiv"),f=e.find(".the-tags"),g=window.tagsBoxL10n.tagDelimiter,h=f.val().split(g),i=[];return delete h[d],a.each(h,function(b,c){c=a.trim(c),c&&i.push(c)}),f.val(this.clean(i.join(g))),this.quickClicks(e),!1},quickClicks:function(b){var c,d,e=a(".the-tags",b),f=a(".tagchecklist",b),g=a(b).attr("id");e.length&&(d=e.prop("disabled"),c=e.val().split(window.tagsBoxL10n.tagDelimiter),f.empty(),a.each(c,function(b,c){var e,h;c=a.trim(c),c&&(e=a("<span />").text(c),d||(h=a('<a id="'+g+"-check-num-"+b+'" class="ntdelbutton" tabindex="0">X</a>'),h.on("click keypress",function(b){("click"===b.type||13===b.keyCode)&&(13===b.keyCode&&a(this).closest(".tagsdiv").find("input.newtag").focus(),tagBox.parseTags(this))}),e.prepend("&nbsp;").prepend(h)),f.append(e))}))},flushTags:function(b,c,d){var e,f,g,h=a(".the-tags",b),i=a("input.newtag",b),j=window.tagsBoxL10n.tagDelimiter;return c=c||!1,g=c?a(c).text():i.val(),"undefined"==typeof g?!1:(e=h.val(),f=e?e+j+g:g,f=this.clean(f),f=array_unique_noempty(f.split(j)).join(j),h.val(f),this.quickClicks(b),c||i.val(""),"undefined"==typeof d&&i.focus(),!1)},get:function(b){var c=b.substr(b.indexOf("-")+1);a.post(ajaxurl,{action:"get-tagcloud",tax:c},function(d,e){0!==d&&"success"==e&&(d=a('<p id="tagcloud-'+c+'" class="the-tagcloud">'+d+"</p>"),a("a",d).click(function(){return tagBox.flushTags(a("#"+c),this),!1}),a("#"+b).after(d))})},init:function(){var b=this,c=a("div.ajaxtag");a(".tagsdiv").each(function(){tagBox.quickClicks(this)}),a(".tagadd",c).click(function(){b.flushTags(a(this).closest(".tagsdiv"))}),a("input.newtag",c).keyup(function(b){return 13==b.which?(tagBox.flushTags(a(this).closest(".tagsdiv")),!1):void 0}).keypress(function(a){return 13==a.which?(a.preventDefault(),!1):void 0}).each(function(){var b=a(this).closest("div.tagsdiv").attr("id");a(this).suggest(ajaxurl+"?action=ajax-tag-search&tax="+b,{delay:500,minchars:2,multiple:!0,multipleSep:window.tagsBoxL10n.tagDelimiter})}),a("#post").submit(function(){a("div.tagsdiv").each(function(){tagBox.flushTags(this,!1,1)})}),a(".tagcloud-link").click(function(){return tagBox.get(a(this).attr("id")),a(this).unbind().click(function(){return a(this).siblings(".the-tagcloud").toggle(),!1}),!1})}}}(jQuery);`

My JS is not so strong, but I'm still not seeing why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Assume you have enabled debug mode, checked the log, etc?  If there's no error thrown, the problem must be a logical one.

Comment: Debug mode did not provide any clues, and Chrome Dev Tools is not giving any JS errors. When I look at the `onclick` calls, they are 'missing' the ones for the link when they are broken, but I can't figure out why. This is from the callback function: `<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a href="#titlediv" class="tagcloud-link" id="link-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>"><?php echo $taxonomy->labels->choose_from_most_used; ?></a></p>` from [WordPress Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L418), but it doesn't give any indication on what might be going wrong.

Comment: In Dev Tools are you seeing the script is a loaded resource?  Any dependencies missing?  Sounds like a tough nut to crack.

Comment: Yes, it calls `load-scripts.php`, and does so successfully on other elements even when this link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

instead of deleting and creating a new box, try this to just move the existing boxes

```
add_action("add_meta_boxes_post", function () {

    $listBoxId = [
        "tagsdiv-ahtscollectionmakes",
        "tagsdiv-ahtscollectionyear",
        "tagsdiv-ahtscollectionos",
    ];


    $screen = get_current_screen();
    $page = $screen->id;

    // loop on the "side" boxes
    foreach ($GLOBALS["wp_meta_boxes"][$page]["side"] as $priority => $tabPriority) {
        foreach ($tabPriority as $id => $box) {

            if (in_array($id, $listBoxId)) {
                // creating new box in "normal"
                $GLOBALS["wp_meta_boxes"][$page]["normal"][$priority][$id] = $box;
                // remove the former box
                unset($GLOBALS["wp_meta_boxes"][$page][$context][$priority][$id]);
            }

        }
    }


});
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: I forget to remove some debug. I edit my answer you can try again